# Permanent account number

Tags: machine-learning, data, numerical

[Permanent account number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_account_number)

PAN is a unique 10 digit alphanumeric. Will there be requirement in future to be changed to a 11 digit alphanumeric taking into consideration the growing population of India?

Example:

Today's Date is 14th March 2050 instead of 14th March 2024.

India's Population: 180 crores instead of 142 crores.

Can prediction machine learning algorithms assist in this regard?

Note: Year 2050 is a future date.